# Trying to use a Bootstrap Tooltip....within a table that is on a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So this one is baffling me and I'm hoping someone has encountered it. I've checked this site for answers but haven't found the correct answer.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.0, and I have a page that has tabbed content, each of which is holding dynamically generated tables. Within those tables, I have dynamically generated content that has a link - and on this link, I am attempting to generate a tooltip.

This makes the structure of the element as such:

- -A Tab
- --A Table
- ---A Row (tr)
- ----A Cell (td)
- -----A link (a data-toggle="tooltip" id="{dynamically generated based on content}" class="specificClassName")

I've put the scripts before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'});
  });
```

I'd link all of the code but it's dynamically generated so I am not sure it would make sense. Ideally, I would like the tooltip to be placed to the right of the link, but I thought perhaps it was attaching itself to the wrong element as a "parent" and not showing up as a result, which is why I changed the placement to top.

Note: I've also tried the class name instead of data-toggle=tooltip, but this did not produce any different results.

The rest of the bootstrap items work- the tab functions correctly, the tables show up as desired. The tooltips are the only item that isn't functioning as intended.

Comment: A little more information is going to need to be provided. Maybe list some error messages or try a create a simple example showing the issue using jsfiddle. I created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ML428/

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: I can't do what I'm trying to do. Or I could, but it's a bad idea. So I'm going to just write custom JS.

Long(er) answer: You have to include a title in a bootstrap tooltip, but the title is the tooltip content. My tooltip content is a dynamically generated div and div content, and I don't want that to be the value of the title property.